# Tips on solving $a^2 (a + 2 b) (a + b^2 + b)^{\frac{3}{2}}>b^3 (a^2 + a + b)^{\frac{3}{2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$$a^2 (a + 2 b) (a + b^2 + b)^{\frac{3}{2}}>b^3 (a^2 + a + b)^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

This is true with $a>b>0$, [according to Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%5E2%20(a%20%2B%202%20b)%20(a%20%2B%20b%5E2%20%2B%20b)%5E(3%2F2)%3Eb%5E3%20(a%5E2%20%2B%20a%20%2B%20b)%5E(3%2F2),%20a%3Eb%3E0), but I am not able to prove this.

---

I to simplify using the fact that $a^2(a+2b)=a^3+2ba^2>3b^3$, and then proving a stronger result:

$$3b^3(a + b^2 + b)^{\frac{3}{2}}>b^3 (a^2 + a + b)^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

$$\iff 3(a + b^2 + b)>(a^2 + a + b)$$

$$\iff 3a + 3b^2 + 3b>a^2 + a + b$$

But this is not true, e.g. $a=100, b=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We prove the stronger result that comes from replacing $a+2b$ on the left by $a$

Note that for $0 \lt b \lt a, \frac 1b \gt \frac 1a$ and $\frac a{b^2} \gt \frac b{a^2}$  Then
$$1+\frac 1b+\frac a{b^2} \gt 1+\frac 1a+\frac b{a^2}\\
\sqrt{1+\frac 1b+\frac a{b^2}} \gt  \sqrt{1+\frac 1a+\frac b{a^2}}\\
ab\sqrt{1+\frac 1b+\frac a{b^2}} \gt ab \sqrt{1+\frac 1a+\frac b{a^2}}\\
a\sqrt{a+b^2+b} \gt b\sqrt{a^2+a+b}\\
a^3(a+b^2+b)^{3/2} \gt b^3(a^2+a+b)^{3/2}\\
a^2(a+2b)(a+b^2+b)^{3/2}\gt b^3(a^2+a+b)^{3/2}$$

Comment: This looks great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try moving all the terms raised to the power of 3/2 onto one side of the equation only, and move all other terms to the other side of the equation. Then square both sides so that the power of 3/2 becomes 3, and use algebra from there.

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.-The points $(a,b)=(1,t)$ for $t\ge4$ does not satisfy the inequality.

Comment: Sorry, I assume $a>b>0$.

Comment: Dear friend, the points I gave are all positive, as you want to have.

Comment: You gave an example with $b>a$.

Comment: Ah, well I'll see it.